# $this->db->insert_id() not working in mysql codeigniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am just trying to get the latest auto generated key from the mysql table from codeiginitor. But it is not working some how. I have tried this code 
`$this->db->insert_id()`  
 as well as 

 `$this->db->mysql_insert_id()`  
I am getting the following error 

`Severity: Notice 

Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_mysql_driver::$insert_id`
 
is the insert_id function not supported for mysql? How can we make it work?

Comment: Does the normal [mysql_insert_id()](http://ro.php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-insert-id.php)  work for you?

Comment: It would help to see where you are running the query before this.

Comment: @sqwk I am able to get Insert id on normal PHP only after installing MySQLi. I assume mysql_insert_id will work only with MySQLi. I wonder how can we make CodeIgnitor to make use of MySQLi

Comment: @Chris I have run the query in mysql command line client as well as PHP program using MYSQLi. But it is not working with CodeIgnitor connection.

Comment: No, let us see all your code, where you're doing the query in codeigniter and then trying to retrieve the insert ID

Comment: Post your insert code, $this->db->insert_id() will only work if you are using the $this->db->insert method. Until you post your code nobody can help you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code I tried to insert the data and get the insert id,

`$this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
$id = $this->db->mysql_insert_id();`

It is not working for me. I have used DB Driver as "mysql". Then I have installed "mysqli" and changed the DB driver name in database.php like, 
`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Now it is working fine for me.

Comment: $this->db->insert(table_name, $data);
return $this->db->insert_id();

Answer (score 12):

CodeIgniter's `insert_id()` will only return an ID of an `insert()`.  Unless you are executing something like `$this->db->insert('table', $data);` before calling the function it will not be able to return an ID.

Comment: I got it working with the following changes. <br> 
1. I changed the dbdriver in config.php from mysql to mysqli <br>
2. using the following code <br>
<code>
    $this->db->mysql_insert_id();
</code>

Comment: obviously the insertion id we are talking is after insert some values using insert statement.

Comment: You never posted the code so I wasn't sure if you were using an Active Record `insert()`.

Answer (score 6):

Use only this syntax

```
$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

return $last_id;
```

Answer (score 3):

Please check if your table don't have auto increment, primary field then `$this->db->insert_id();` will not return anything.

Comment: In my case this method helped me and resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and found a solution with this link: http://kedyr.wordpress.com/2012/10/03/codeigniter-insert_id/

The solution is not properly a solution, because it's just a way to get around by using the native sql, with the codeigniter method "Query" and dealing with the native sql callback.

```
    $this->db->insert('references', $data);
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()');
    $row = $query->row_array();
    $LastIdInserted = $row['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];
```

Comment: In a multiuser environment, this solution is a mess!

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are using active record pattern
this should work
`$this->db->insert_id()`

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$id = $this->db->insert_id()
```

instead of

```
$id = $this->db->mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Store data into array
$data=array('name'=>'Rudra','email'=>'test@gmail.com');

//Insert Data Query
$this->db->insert('tableName',$data);

// Storing id into varialbe
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
return $id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
$id = $this->db->mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work if you have a code like this :

```
var $table = 'your table name'
$this->db->insert($this->table,$data1);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
```

CodeIgniter's insert_id() will only return an ID of an insert(), as mention before, and also you dont forget to settings the DB driver name in database.php like

`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';`

Answer (score 0):

```
// insert data
$data=array("name"=>"vijay");
$this->db->insert("table_name",$data);
$insert_id= $this->db->insert_id();
```

Comment: It better to add some description in the answer

Answer (score -2):

If you are using ajax to insert data, then print the output you will get the id in response, or if you are using core codeigniter method then use below code.

```
$last_id = $this->db->insert_id();
return $last_id;
```